# How to convert main to a function

Tags: c

Can someone please help me convert this code into a function so that I can call it later on the main?

This is my `main()` function

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        t_node  *group_a;
        t_node  *group_b;
    
        group_a = NULL;
        group_b = NULL;
        if (argc > 1)
        {
            group_a = create_list(argc - 1, argv);
            if (is_sorted(&group_a) == 0)
            {
                if (list_len(&group_a) > 1 && list_len(&group_a) <= 3) 
                    sorting_3(&group_a);
                else if (list_len(&group_a) > 3 && list_len(&group_a) <= 5)
                    sorting_5(&group_a, &group_b);
                else if (list_len(&group_a) > 5 && list_len(&group_a) < 500)
                    sort(&group_a, &group_b, 5);
                else if (list_len(&group_a) >= 500)
                    sort(&group_a, &group_b, 11);
            }
        }
        remove_list(&group_a);
        remove_list(&group_b);
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: `main` is a function.

Comment: What problems did you have when you made it into a function with a different name?

Comment: Could be as simple as: `int foo(int argc, char **argv)`.  `main` calls `foo` like this: `foo(argc, argv)`.

Comment: @Lebza - How do you want to _call it later on the main_?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new function and put the code from your main function in it, then call that new function later, for example

```
int     foo(int argc, char **argv)
{
        t_node  *group_a;
        t_node  *group_b;

        group_a = NULL;
        group_b = NULL;
        if (argc > 1)
        {
            group_a = create_list(argc - 1, argv);
            if (is_sorted(&group_a) == 0)
            {
                if (list_len(&group_a) > 1 && list_len(&group_a) <= 3) 
                    sorting_3(&group_a);
                else if (list_len(&group_a) > 3 && list_len(&group_a) <= 5)
                    sorting_5(&group_a, &group_b);
                else if (list_len(&group_a) > 5 && list_len(&group_a) < 500)
                    sort(&group_a, &group_b, 5);
                else if (list_len(&group_a) >= 500)
                    sort(&group_a, &group_b, 11);
            }
        }
        remove_list(&group_a);
        remove_list(&group_b);
        return (0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   //Your code here, then calling the function next,
   foo(argc, argv);
   return 0;
}
```